# .desktop files - Allow launching - set this via CLI

Tags: symbolic-link

I‘m customizing a Ubuntu Live (19.10) system and created .desktop files for installed applications. When booted up, I need to rightclick these files and choose „Allow launching“. Can I automate this somehow? Is there a CLI command for „Allow launching“?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above answers are only part of the solution. The order (!) of the commands matters and you need both. For Ubuntu 20.04.LTS:

1. copy to desktop `cp app.desktop ~/Desktop`
2. set trusted status `gio set ~/Desktop/app.desktop metadata::trusted true`
3. allow execution `chmod a+x ~/Desktop/app.desktop`

If you switch 2) and 3) it won't work.
This is the same as right-clicking on the file and clicking `Allow Launching`

Comment: In [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73455006/6543935) I have to switch the order to 3) then 2) to achieve the result.

Answer (score 2):

It can be set with

```sh
gio set file.desktop metadata::trusted true
```

or with yes if true is not accepted

```sh
gio set file.desktop metadata::trusted yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Those .desktop files are called "starters". Depending on which desktop environment / window manager you're using (and on the version of Ubuntu), you may need to make your starter executable so Ubuntu "trusts" it. You can make a starter executable like with any other file by setting a suitable mode, for example

```
chmod u+x /some/where/my_starter.desktop
```

Comment: There must be some second stage of trust level, making it executable alone does not work. https://i.imgur.com/MARMEsN.png

Comment: somehow the file ~/.local/share/gvfs-metdata/root is involved, it saves the "allow launching" state