# .Desktop files are opening text files and not launching Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

*Note that I am very new to using Linux, any help is appreciated.

I have tried the options that are in the comments below, both through the graphical interface as well as through the CLI through the chmod command. Unfortunately, both did not work

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Downvote(s) are likely because of how you've written it.  The "*Can I ser*.." paragraph is written as a rant in disguise which is off-topic on this site, please refer to  https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask   (*I'd suggest removing that paragraph unless your aim is to be closed for being off-topic b/c of the rant paragraph*)

Comment: `cat .local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`  please add this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

### GUI

1. `Right click` the `.desktop` file
2. Click `Properties`
3. Navigate to the `Permissions` tab
4. Tick the box that says `Allow executing file as program`

### CLI

`chmod +x /path/to/your/file.desktop`

Worst thing that should happen after doing one of the above is that it'll ask you if you want to open the file in an editor or execute it as a program.

Otherwise you should be good to go!

Comment: `.desktop` files are merely text files. You need to tell the OS (in this case Ubuntu) that you want it to be executable. Main reason for this (to my knowledge at least) is that Linux determines what a file is based off it's structure, not what it's file extension is (like Windows does, for example.)

Comment: Some years ago, the automatic launching of applications was disabled for security reasons, to protect users from accidentally executing malicious applications. (Sorry, I don't have a link).

Comment: You missed a very important bit. When a .desktop file is present on the desktop, you need to right-click it, and in the appearing context menu, you need to click the "**Allow launching**" context menu item. This is not equivalent with the "allow executing file as program" property. When you click it, the icon will change from a generic one to the one defined inside the file.

Comment: I have tried now [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1310690/1157519) in hopes that it can be achieved via the cli too, but it does not seem to make any difference; so right-click it is then, until we find out the cli method.

Comment: Additionally, the executable bit, that you point to in your answer (`chmod +x`) is unrelated whether the desktop file can be launched or not. I have just revoked it from a desktop file (that I allowed launching via the context menu as introduced in my above comment), and it happily opens the application, even though it's not set as executable.

Comment: The Wiki Page for desktop launchers was last edited in 2013 (for Ubuntu Unity), and it also indicates that the `*.desktop` file must be executable by all. This leads me to estimate that the protective security feature was implemented around Ubuntu 13.04 or prior. This has been the default behavior for a very long time. Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Comment: Yes but we have a Gnome 3 desktop now, as Ubuntu ships with it by default since 2017. It's not proof for the change however; the proof is that I have just tried it out (on Ubuntu 20.04.2 with gnome-shell 3.36.7), and it launched without being executable.

Comment: @Levente, I'm just pointing out that Canonical/Ubuntu made a decision to not allow `*.desktop` files to launch applications by default. I actually remember when that change was made because it took a little getting used to. This decision has carried over to present day; the explanation given for the change was to improve security, and I'm sure that justification still applies today. Also, Gnome doesn't launch the application-- the application launching behavior is independent of the DE; it works this way in Kubuntu, Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, etc.

Comment: My experiment was false. I have copied a file out from `~/.local/share/applications` to `~/Desktop` to experiment with it, but I left its name intact: did not make its name unique. That interfered with my results. Renaming the file in `~/Desktop` to a unique name yielded that clicking the context menu's "Allow / Don't allow lanunching" item automatically syncs the executable bit also. So in effect, it indeed needs to be executable too.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, but since all what is done via the graphical interface can (*fortunately*) be done using command line(*s*), this still does not tell us what command line(*s*) must be used to replicate **the two actions** of selecting the graphical option "Allow Launching" of the right click menu of a starter of the Desktop, theses two actions being:

1. displaying **immediately** the icon related to the starter (*if any described in the related .desktop file*) and
2. making **immediately** the starter "launchable" when doing a double click on the starter!

So, is this a Defense Secret of Canonical that they refuse to share?

It seams to be since this question was posted multiple times with different wording almost a year and a half ago and still never received any answer yet.

[image]

A clear response to that simple question would save a lot of time to a bunch of us desperately googeling for a while on this subject. ;)

TIA